# data.table lag of one column

Tags: r, data.table

Not sure why this isn't working:

```
dt = data.table(a = 1:10)
dt[, c := stats::lag(a)]
```

looks like the new column `c` is identical to `a` instead of `a` lagged.

Answer (score 3):

We can use the `shift` function from `data.table`.  By default, the `type` is "lag" and `n = 1`

```
dt[, c:= shift(a)]
```

---

According to `?stats::lag`

> Compute a lagged version of a time series, shifting the time base back by a given number of observations.

So, if we apply it on a time series

```
ts(dt$a, freq = 12, start = c(2019, 4))
#     Jan Feb Mar Apr May Jun Jul Aug Sep Oct Nov Dec
#2019               1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9
#2020  10                                            


stats::lag(ts(dt$a, freq = 12, start = c(2019, 4)))
#.    Mar Apr May Jun Jul Aug Sep Oct Nov Dec
#2019   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9  10
```

Comment: @R.M.  the `lag` from `stats` is appied on time series data `stats::lag(ts(dt$a, freq = 12))`

Comment: Yeah, per the quoted doc, core data is not modified by lag, just the time base attribute. Eg, `x = 1:3; identical(x, c(stats::lag(x)))`